# Quickest way to clone row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to clone multiple tables' rows that have a single primary key (PrimKey). What's the quickest way to clone a row in SQL Server 2005?

Here's an example,

Clone PrimKey1 to get PrimKey2. So I try the following :

```
INSERT INTO PrimKeys 
SELECT 'PrimKey2' AS PrimKey,* 
  FROM PrimKeys 
 WHERE PrimKey='PrimKey1'
```

But of course the issue here is, the column PrimKey gets repeated in the inner SELECT statement. Is there any other way similar in simplicity to the above?

---

Thank you all for your responses. I went ahead and wrote a function that handles that in my application. I don't use Stored Procs or Temp tables so I couldn't use a couple of valid answers posted by some of you.

Comment: Quickest as in 'fastest to type' ? Never use * in SELECT and never use implicit column lists in INSERT.

Comment: Thanks Remus but that didn't answer my question.

Comment: Neither did you answer Remus's question, which is pretty important.

Comment: Quickest as in least number of characters and most generic. If I don't use *, the whole Generic requirement would go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are cloning from multiple tables, the fastest way will be to use a stored procedure, so that all the queries stay on the database, and you don't pay a price for communication between the client and the server.

Once you do that, then start unit-testing, to see how long it takes to do the operation.  Then begin experimenting with changing it, based on suggestions you get, and see if you get any improvement.

Comment: @James Black: I think the poster is inferring that it will done 'on the database' server...

Comment: It sounds like the poster wants to make multiple queries from an app to do the cloning, and that will be slower than a stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

You can run something like the stored procedure below to avoid typing out all of the column names. The example below assumes an int, but you can swap the key type out for any data type.

```sql
create procedure [CloneRow]
    @tableName varchar(max),
    @keyName varchar(max),
    @oldKeyId int,
    @newTableId int output
as
    declare @sqlCommand nvarchar(max),
            @columnList varchar(max);

    select  @columnList = coalesce(@columnList + ',','') + sys.columns.name
    from    sys.columns
    where   object_name(sys.columns.object_id) = @tableName
        and sys.columns.name not in ( @keyName )
        and is_computed = 0;

    set @sqlCommand = 'insert into ' + @tableName + ' ( ' + @columnList + ') (' +
        'select ' + @columnList + ' from ' + @tableName + ' where ' + @keyName + ' = @oldKeyId )'
    exec sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@oldKeyId int', @oldKeyId = @oldKeyId
    select @newTableId = @@identity -- note scope_identity() won't work here!
GO
```

You call it like this:

```
declare @newOrderId int
exec [CloneRow] 'orderTable', 'orderId', 625911, @newOrderId output
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most beautiful solution, but I think it will work for you. First of all, you select your data into a temporary table with a "new" primary key and next you drop the old primary key column from the temp table and use the temp table to insert your "cloned" row.

```
SELECT 
'PrimKey2' AS NewPrimKey,
*
INTO #TMP 
FROM PrimKeys 
WHERE PrimKey='PrimKey1';

ALTER TABLE #TMP DROP COLUMN PrimKey;

INSERT INTO PrimKeys
SELECT * FROM #TMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by "multiple tables' rows that have a single primary key".

`PRIMARY KEY`, by definition, is `UNIQUE`.

To do your query you need to enumerate all columns:

```
INSERT
INTO    PrimKeys (PrimKey, col1, col2, …)
SELECT  'PrimKey2' AS PrimKey, col1, col2, …
FROM    PrimKeys
WHERE   PrimKey = 'PrimKey1'
```

Comment: Yah I was trying to avoid this. The reason is, I have 55 tables and they all have one thing in common. They have a primary key called "Order ID" for example. If I use your method, then I would need to know every single column number of each of the 55 tables. I was looking for a way to loop through the 55 tables and generate more generic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you need to perform generic operations against a large number of tables, then dynamic SQL and the system tables are your friends.

Short of that, Hakan's solution will work for non-identity PKs. I would tighten it up to:

```
SELECT * INTO #TMP 
FROM PrimKeys 
WHERE PrimKey='PrimKey1';

UPDATE #TMP SET PrimeKey = 'PrimeKey2';

INSERT INTO PrimKeys
SELECT * FROM #TMP;
```

For identity PKs, change the UPDATE above to a DROP COLUMN:

```
SELECT * INTO #TMP 
FROM PrimKeys 
WHERE PrimKey=101;

ALTER TABLE #TMP DROP COLUMN PrimeKey;

INSERT INTO PrimKeys
SELECT * FROM #TMP;
```

Comment: This solution (see Hakan's below) is a good one. What is nice about using a SELECT INTO #temp method is that you copy all of the columns in the table, even those that were added after your code was written. Unfortunately it does not work with SQL Azure, which does not support SELECT INTO.